# Parsing the first <td> value in the first and last <tr> of a <table> with JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I've been able to use JSoup successfully to parse an entire page, however I've encountered a bit of a challenge to parse the first `<td>` and in the first and last `<tr>` of a table. Especially seeing as the number of table rows changes throughout the length of the day.

So far I understand that I need to get the table from within the page so I'm using this `doc.select("table.tabular zebra").toString();` (although I don't know how to deal with the space in the table class, but that's a separate problem).

The sample table is below:

```
<table id="tradesTableE_PPT_L0" class="tabular zebra" style="float:left; margin-right:10px">
<caption>Latest trades</caption>

<thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="tradeTime" title="The time the trade was published">Time</th>
      <th id="tradePrice" title="The trade price">Price</th>
      <th id="tradeVolume" title="Number of shares traded">Volume</th>
      <th id="tradeTotalPrice" title="Total value of bargain">Value</th>
      <th id="bidPrice" title="Best bid at time of trade">Bid</th>
      <th id="askPrice" title="Best ask at time of trade">Ask</th>
      <th id="tradeType" title="Buy/Sell indicator"><a href="#types" style="color=#0000CC">B/S</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr align="right">
  <th>16:22:40</th>
    <td>204p</td>
    <td>2,500</td>
    <td>&pound;5,100</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td align="center" style='color:blue;'>Buy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
  <th>16:05:23</th>
    <td>200p</td>
    <td>2,500</td>
    <td>&pound;5,000</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td align="center" style='color:blue;'>Buy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
  <th>15:59:51</th>
    <td>197p</td>
    <td>1,000</td>
    <td>&pound;1,970</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td>192.5p</td>
    <td align="center" style='color:blue;'>Buy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: An element with two classes can be selected with either one or if both are required then `table.tabular.zebra` is what you would use. There are no spaces in class names a element can have more than one class separated by spaces.

Comment: So `Tabular Zebra` are actually two classes. Not one with a space?

Comment: How come there's <th> tags in the <tbody>?

Comment: @LanceJava, I have no idea. It's just how it is.

Comment: Nearest I can figure out the doc select should look like this `doc.select("table.tabular.zebra").select("tr").size().select("td").get(1).toString();`. But it's still not quite right.

Comment: Lance, I've written HTML like that (I'm not proud of it, but I can admit it) to make styling a row header easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

For the first row:

```
doc.select("[id^=tradesTableE_]").select("tr").get(1).select("td").get(0).text().toString();
```

and for the last row:

```
doc.select("[id^=tradesTableE_]").select("tr").last().select("td").get(0).text().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing table elements can get very messy. In the past I had to use selenium to verify values in a table. I found that parsing the whole table HTML into a developer friendly object helped me to drastically simplify the code. Without it, there were lots of messy xpath selectors in the code which made it difficult to read / maintain.

eg:

```
TableWithHeaders table = MyHtmlUtils.parseTableWithHeaders(dom, "//[id=tradesTableE_PPT_L0]");
assertEquals(3, table.getRowCount());
assertEquals("204p", table.getCellText("Price", 0));
assertEquals("1,000", table.getCellText("Volume", 2));

public interface TableWithHeaders {
   int getRowCount();
   Collection<String> getHeaderNames();
   String getCellText(String header, int row);
   Element getCell(String header, int row);
   ...
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the asserts?